# Explicit type conversion in Scala 3 macros

Tags: scala, generics, tuples, scala-macros, scala-3

I defined the following trait in Scala 3:

```
trait A[T <: Tuple]
```

Using Scala 3 macros, I then create objects of this trait performing further checks on the actual types of the tuple `T`; in particular, I want to check that all the types (`T_1`, …, `T_n`) of the tuple `T` are subtypes of another given type, `B`:

```
trait B
private def allSubtypesOfB[T <: Tuple: Type](using quotes: Quotes): Boolean = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    case '[Nothing] => false // I don't want nothing to be in T
    case '[head *: tail] if TypeRepr.of[head] <:< TypeRepr.of[B] => allSubtypesOfB[tail]
    case '[EmptyTuple] => true
    case _ => false
}

inline def createA[T <: Tuple] = ${ createAImpl[T] }
private def createAImpl[T <: Tuple: Type](using quotes: Quotes): Expr[A[T]] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    if !allSubtypesOfB[T] then report.error("All types in T must be subtypes of B")
    // ... create instance of A
}
```

The problem is that later I need to call, for each type in the tuple type `T`, a method that has the following signature:

```
def doSomethingWithBSubtype[T <: B] = ??? // Do something with type T
```

So, the code would look something like this:

```
private def createAImpl[T <: Tuple: Type](using quotes: Quotes): Expr[A[T]] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    if !allSubtypesOfB[T] then report.error("All types in T must be subtypes of B")
    Type.of[T] match {
        case '[head *: tail] => doSomethingWithBSubtype[head]
        case '[EmptyTuple] => ???
    }
    // ... create instance of A
}
```

This code won't compile as the compiler says that `head` must be a subtype of `B` to be used in the method `doSomethingWithBSubtype`. However, with the `if` preceding the `match` case, I already ensured that all types inside `T` are subtypes of `B`. Is there a way to force the compiler to recognise `head` as a subtype of `B`?

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 2):

There are compile time and runtime of macros. There are compile time and runtime of main code (using the macros). The runtime of macros is the compile time of main code.

Inside `createAImpl` the line `if !allSubtypesOfB[T]...` ensures that all types of `T` are subtypes of `B` at the runtime of `createAImpl`. But when you call `doSomethingWithBSubtype[head]` you need to know that `head` is a subtype of `B` at the compile time of `createAImpl` so you don't have information from the runtime of `createAImpl` yet (`if !allSubtypesOfB[T]...`).

You could do

```
case '[head *: tail] => doSomethingWithBSubtype[head & B]
```

Also maybe something like the following is possible

```
Type.of[T] match {
  case '[head *: tail] =>
    '{foo[head]} match {
      case '{
        type h <: B
        foo[`h`]
      } => doSomethingWithBSubtype[h]
    }
  case '[EmptyTuple] => ???
}

// outside def createAImpl, otherwise "access to method foo from wrong staging level"
def foo[A] = ???
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html#type-variables-in-quoted-patterns

> In some cases we need to define a pattern variable that is referenced several times or has some type bounds. To achieve this, it is possible to create pattern variables at the start of the pattern using `type t` with a type pattern variable.

[fuseMap macro in scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550568/fusemap-macro-in-scala-3)

[What Scala 3 syntax can match on a Type and its Type parameters in the context of a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311751/what-scala-3-syntax-can-match-on-a-type-and-its-type-parameters-in-the-context-o)

[Get information of type in Scala3 macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422689/get-information-of-type-in-scala3-macro)

[Turning inlined varargs into a generic tuple](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/discussions/12651)