# fuseMap macro in scala 3

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

Following the metaprogramming tutorial [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/quotes.html), I am unable to get the fuseMap example to work. The macro I have is (in `macros` object)

```scala
  def fuseMap[T: Type](x: Expr[List[T]])(using Quotes): Expr[List[T]] =
    println("Initial passed in x: " + x.show)
    x match {
      case '{
            type u
            type v
            ($ls: List[`u`])
              .map($f: `u` => `v`)
              .map($g: `v` => T)
          } =>
        '{ $ls.map(y => $g($f(y))) }
        val result = '{ $ls.map(y => $g($f(y))) }

        println(result.show)
        result
      case _ =>
        println("fuseMap didn't do anything")
        x
    }

  inline def simplify[T](x: List[T]): List[T] = ${ fuseMap('x) }
```

And calling it in seperate file like

```scala
object macrofun extends App {

  val l = List(1, 2, 3)
  val f = (x: Int) => x + 1
  val g = (y: Int) => y * 2

  val r = simplify {
    List(1, 2, 3)
      .map(f)
      .map(g)
  }

  println(s"Result of l is $r")

}
```

I would expect to see the simplified code printed out on compile but instead I see "fuseMap didn't do anything".

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this work by making the argument to `simplify` inline like

```scala
inline def simplify[T](inline x: List[T]): List[T] = ${ fuseMap('x) }
```